# CakePHP custom validation rule causes error message on multiple fields

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a few custom validation functions in my model. For example, in some fields I have a validation rule that checks if any HTML is the text. My problem is that when I use that same validation rule on two fields, the error message in the view appear on BOTH fields, even if only one failed failed validation.

Ex:

```
    'field1' => array(
        'noTags' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'detectTags' ),
            'message' => 'HTML tags are not allowed.'
        )
    ),
    'field2' => array(
        'noTags' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'detectTags' ),
            'message' => 'HTML tags are not allowed.'
        )
    ),
...

public function detectTags($check) {
    $value = array_values($check);
    $string = $value[0];
    return ($string == strip_tags($string)); 
}
```

I already have a workaround (see below) for this. I wrap the validation rule with a unique function for each field and everything works fine. But this is annoying. And I suspect there is a better way. What is it?

```
    'field1' => array(
        'noTags' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'detectTags1' ),
            'message' => 'HTML tags are not allowed.'
        )
    ),
    'field2' => array(
        'noTags' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'detectTags2' ),
            'message' => 'HTML tags are not allowed.'
        )
    ),
...

public function detectTags1($check) {
    return $this->_detectTags($check);
}
public function detectTags2($check) {
    return $this->_detectTags($check);
}
private function _detectTags($check) {
    $value = array_values($check);
    $string = $value[0];
    return ($string == strip_tags($string)); 
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to recreate this issue with latest stable. What version of CakePHP are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    'field1' => array(
        'noTags1' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'detectTags' ),
            'message' => 'HTML tags are not allowed.'
        )
    ),
    'field2' => array(
        'noTags2' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'detectTags' ),
            'message' => 'HTML tags are not allowed.'
        )
    ),
```